# How can I disable sleep/slumber function?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I make it so that my app does not go into sleep, keeping the app alive and focused as long as its running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is to run the application [under the lock screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx). You can't prevent the device from sleeping.